# bash for parsing all strings between triple curly brackets

Tags: string, bash, awk, sed

I have the following text:

```
{{{VSER}}} is doing well. He went to {{{MARKET}}}.
It is very useful {{{RESOURCE}}}
```

I would like to parse string between `{{{` and `}}}` run a script `echo $TEXT | somescript`, then the result should be:

```
VSER
MARKET
RESOURCE
```

Trying with sed:

```
echo $TEXT | sed 's/.*{{{ //' | sed # /}}}.*$//'
```

However, it returns `{{{VSER` , even `VSER` is not returned.

Comment: could you add the exact command you tried? `echo $TEXT | sed 's/.*{{{ //' | sed # /}}}.*$//'` has several issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found!

```
echo $TEXT | awk -vRS="}}}" -vFS="{{{" '{print $2}'
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: you could add a note that this is gawk specific due to multi character RS

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU grep` having PCRE available:

```
$ TEXT='{{{VSER     123}}} is doing well. He went to {{{MARKET}}}.
It is very useful {{{RESOURCE}}}'

$ echo $TEXT | grep -oP '\{\{\{\K.*?(?=}}})'
VSER 123
MARKET
RESOURCE

$ echo "$TEXT" | grep -oP '\{\{\{\K.*?(?=}}})'
VSER     123
MARKET
RESOURCE

$ # with perl
$ echo "$TEXT" | perl -lne 'print join "\n", /\{\{\{\K.*?(?=}}})/g'
VSER     123
MARKET
RESOURCE
```